# Difference between Business Delegate and View Helper

Tags: design-patterns

They seem to do the same thing - seperate Presentation tier logic from complexities of Business tier. So what is the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both try to separate complexities of components, but:

- **View Helper**'s intent is to make Views lighter (make them only *display* stuff, really);
- **Business Delegate** intends to decouple any two components (leaving the details of the **plumbing work** to a third one that will be *in between* them).

I can see where your confusion comes from, as they look alike in a way. But, in practice, they address two different issues:

## View Helper

As systems grow, people tend to start putting code on the View, say JSP, and it begins to get more and more complex. Views aren't supposed to have a lot of code. They are supposed to only display data. If you put a heavy calculation in a JSP, for instance, on one hand the code will be hidden amongst HTML tags and, on the other, you can't reuse it anywhere in the system. Imagine having to do some maintenance in a code like this. You'd go crazy.

**View Helper** teaches you a way you can avoid that by making **Views simpler** through the creation of a `Helper` class to do the heavy work and make the JSP call for it instead of keeping all the complex code **inside** the JSP.

## Business Delegate

When you have a component, say `MyCalculator`, that calls an external component (say an EJB `WeatherEJB`) that changes a lot, you end up having to change your component a lot too.

Think of `MyCalculator`, for instance, as a very important class of your system, you'll not want to change it all the time. What if you break something else? What if someone is also changing it at another branch?

Besides, you'll only want to change `MyCalculator` when **your** business change, not everytime someone else changes.

You'll see this getting even crazier when `MyCalculator` calls like **ten** other components. You'll be changing it everyday!

*Business Delegate* comes to the rescue advising: add a class `WeatherDelegate` that can perform calls to `WeatherEJB` and make `MyCalculator` use it instead of calling `WeatherEJB` directly.

This way, everytime the `WeatherEJB` changes, you don't need to change `MyCalculator`. All you'll need to do is edit `WeatherDelegate` accordingly. <sup>(Also, if someday you wish to change the way you get the weather for a, say, web service, once again, all you'd have to edit is the `WeatherDelegate`.)</sup>

## In the end...

...they both say: create someone to do some work for you. But *View Helper* says that so you don't do unecessary work on the View; and *Business Delegate* tells you to decouple some components, so you system's responsibilities are better distributed. Both make the system easier to maintain.